# How to create a function and pass a variable to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to js but not so much jQuery, so I don't know exactly what to search for in order to answer my question, hoping someone here can help me.

In short - I have a very simple bit of jQuery that checks the next and previous elements. I want to make this a little tidier by having the function separate.

Here's my current code:

```
$(function() {

    $('.filmstrip img').on('click', function(){
        var new_src = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $('.mainView img.current').attr('src', new_src);

        //get the previous element's data source
        var prevImg = $(this).closest("li + *").prev().find('img').attr('data-src');
        if(prevImg === undefined){
            console.log('there isnt a prev img');
        }
        if(prevImg != undefined){
            console.log('the previous image is: '+prevImg);
        }

        //get the next element's data source
        var nextImg = $(this).closest("li + *").next().find('img').attr('data-src');
        if(nextImg === undefined & prevImg != undefined){
            console.log('You are at the last image');
        }
        if(nextImg != undefined){
            console.log('the next image is: '+nextImg);
        }

    });

});
```

and here's what I'm aiming for (note: this doesn't work as expected):

```
$(function() {

    $('.filmstrip img').on('click', function(){
        var new_src = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $('.mainView img.current').attr('src', new_src);
        getThePrevAndNextImages();
    });

    function getThePrevAndNextImages(){
        //get the previous element's data source
        var prevImg = $(this).closest("li + *").prev().find('img').attr('data-src');
        if(prevImg === undefined){
            console.log('there isnt a prev img');
        }
        if(prevImg != undefined){
            console.log('the previous image is: '+prevImg);
        }

        //get the next element's data source
        var nextImg = $(this).closest("li + *").next().find('img').attr('data-src');
        if(nextImg === undefined & prevImg != undefined){
            console.log('You are at the last image');
        }
        if(nextImg != undefined){
            console.log('the next image is: '+nextImg);
        }
    }

});
```

I think the reason this isn't working is because it's not passing the active element through?

What I'm getting to console.log is: "there isnt a prev img".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your previous implementation every statement was under the event handler. Where you were using `this` which represents the element that was clicked on.  But in the context of the function. this does not exist. **So the solution is to pass in the clicked element**.

*Use*

```
$(function () {
    $('.filmstrip img').on('click', function () {
        var new_src = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $('.mainView img.current').attr('src', new_src);
        getThePrevAndNextImages(this);
    });

    function getThePrevAndNextImages(obj) {
        //get the previous element's data source
        var prevImg = $(obj).closest("li + *").prev().find('img').attr('data-src');
        if (prevImg === undefined) {
            console.log('there isnt a prev img');
        }
        if (prevImg != undefined) {
            console.log('the previous image is: ' + prevImg);
        }
        //get the next element's data source
        var nextImg = $(obj).closest("li + *").next().find('img').attr('data-src');
        if (nextImg === undefined & prevImg != undefined) {
            console.log('You are at the last image');
        }
        if (nextImg != undefined) {
            console.log('the next image is: ' + nextImg);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes.  By way of explanation: You're correct about the active element.  In the context of the `click` event handler, `this` represents the element that was clicked on.  But in the context of the function., `this` does not. So the solution is to pass in the clicked element.

Comment: You probably meant `getThePrevAndNextImages(this);`

Comment: @JacobM, I am using your explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is basically the "this" reference in the getThePrevAndNextImages function. The way that function is being called there is no "this" inside the function.

If you changed the first code block to the following...

```
$('.filmstrip img').on('click', function(){
    var new_src = $(this).attr('data-src');
    $('.mainView img.current').attr('src', new_src);
    getThePrevAndNextImages.apply(this);
});
```

then it should work. Here is your snippet a little simplified so it isn't dependant on your specific html structure, it only needs three images in a row to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

```
 $(function() {

    $('img').on('click', function() {
        getThePrevAndNextImages.apply(this);
    });

    function getThePrevAndNextImages(){

        var prevImg = $(this).prev('img');
        if(prevImg === undefined){
            console.log('there isnt a prev img');
        }
        if(prevImg != undefined){
            console.log('the previous image is: '+prevImg);
        }

        var nextImg = $(this).next('img');

        if(nextImg === undefined & prevImg != undefined){
            console.log('You are at the last image');
        }
        if(nextImg != undefined){
            console.log('the next image is: '+nextImg);
        }
    }

});
```

And some html to run it with...

```
<img src="/test1.jpg" id="test1"/>
<img src="/test2.jpg" id="test2"/>
<img src="/test3.jpg" id="test3"/>
```

drop that stuff into jsfiddle and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time on this, I completely get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should just change the way you call the function:

```
$('.filmstrip img').on('click', function () {
    var new_src = $(this).attr('data-src');
    $('.mainView img.current').attr('src', new_src);
    getThePrevAndNextImages.call(this);
});
```

this way you are passing the `this` as the current context to your `getThePrevAndNextImages` function.